# Mocking IEnumerable<T> for each class that implements <T> using Moq

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I have the following interface

```
public interface ICommand<TResult, TModel>
{
    Task<TResult> DoWorkAsync(TModel model);
}
```

Which is implemented by one or more such Command classes:

```
public class MyCommand1 : ICommand<Response, Model>()
{
    public async Task<Response> DoWorkAsync(Model model) {
        // do something
    }
}

public class MyCommand2 : ICommand<Response, Model>()
{
    public async Task<Response> DoWorkAsync(Model model) {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

The Respose and Model classes are as follows:

```
public class Response
{
    public bool IsSuccessful {get;set;}
}

public class Model
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Then I have an orchestrator class that has a dependency on an IEnumerable of `IEnumerable<ICommand<Response, Model>>`

```
public class MyOrchestrator
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<ICommand<Response, Model>> _commands;

    public MyOrchestrator(IEnumerable<ICommand<Response, Model>> commands)
    {
        _commands = commands;
    }

    public async Task ExecuteAsync(Model model)
    {
        myCommand1_Response = await _commands
                                    .OfType<MyCommand1>()
                                    .First()
                                    .DoWorkAsync(model);

        myCommand2_Response = await _commands
                                    .OfType<MyCommand2>()
                                    .First()
                                    .DoWorkAsync(model);

        // other operations
    }
}
```

Now in my test I'm trying to mock the MyOrchestrator class's dependency `IEnumerable<ICommand<Response, Model>>` for each of the MyCommand types. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are the Response and Model classes always as you shown? (If so there is no need to use generics).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Could you be more clear which part are you testing? For exmple, are you testing the `ExecuteAsync` method?

Comment: @tymtam Its better that its a generic, because it might be used elsewhere for other Commands. To be able to test `ExecuteAsync` I have to mock the responses from `DoWorkAsync` for each of the Command classes shown in the example.

Comment: Show what you have tried and what error(s) if any that occur

Comment: right now the subject under test is tightly coupled to implementation concerns that make isolating it difficult (especially for MOQ) for unit testing

Comment: It is a code smell to be injecting the abstractions only to cast back to their implementations (tight coupling).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that MyCommand2 and MyCommand1 are concrete classes. You'll either need to make them be IMyCommand1 and IMyCommand2 or make `DoWorkAsync` virtual.

Comment: Since both commands implement `DoWorkAsync`, I don't want to create separate interfaces like IMyCommand1. That's the point of a single ICommand interface.

Comment: If you want to mock them and distinquish between commands of type 1 and 2 then you'd need to. (Wanting to distinguish between 1 and 2 is the reason you have 2 types that otherwise are identical).

Answer (score 0):

I think you could simplify your orchestator which would make mocking trivial.

```
public class MyOrchestrator
{
    ...

    public MyOrchestrator(ICommand<Response, Model> command1, ICommand<Response, Model> command2)
    {
        this.command1 = command1 ?? throw...;
        this.command2 = command2 ?? throw...;
    }

    public async Task ExecuteAsync(Model model)
    {
        myCommand1_Response = await command1.DoWorkAsync(model);

        myCommand2_Response = await command1.DoWorkAsync(model);

        // other operations
    }
}
```

Now mocking this is nothing special.

```
var mockCommand1 = new Mock<ICommand<Response, Model>>(MockBehaviour.Strict);
...

var tested = new MyOrchestrator(command1: mockCommand1.Object, ...);
```

Comment: Problem is that if there are more commands, then I'd need to pass them all individually as opposed to as an IEnumerable.